# FaceBook share button to post content on FaceBook

Tags: facebook

i have added facebook share button on my site, by clicking on that button i want to post content on facebook.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the code for it here: http://www.facebook.com/share/

With documentation here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share

You can use meta tags to control the thumbnail and description.  The title comes from your sites title.

Consider also the Like and Recommend button: http://developers.facebook.com/plugins